# SQL Server Compact Edition query log

Tags: sql-server-ce

There is a need to log all the queries (logging of warnings/errors is not required) an app performs to a SQL server CE database. Something similar to MySQL's log should do. Are there any solutions that might help with this?

No, I am unable to debug the app due to lack of the source code.

EDIT: The app runs under Cassini, so no fancy IIS tools are of use here too.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Server Compact Edition Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173017%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) may be of some help for logging errors and warnings but SQL CE has no transaction log so transaction logging is not possible without some manual change tracking